# Error in working with characters and strings (java)

Tags: java

The output of my program is "Afmmz Ampq". It should be "Cfmmz Gmpq". This only occurs with capital letters so it should be from this sections of the programming.

```
char newLetter=alphabet.charAt(newLetterIndex);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(letter)==true){
                char upper = Character.toUpperCase(newLetter);
                newLetter=upper;
```

Here's the entire code for context

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word= ("Belly Flop");
    int x=1; //decoding variable, for Captain Crunch it is 13
    crunch (word, x);
}
public static void crunch(String word,int x) {
    String alphabet= ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    int index=0;
    while (index<word.length()) {
        char letter=word.charAt(index);
        if (letter==' ') {
            System.out.print (" ");
            index++;
        } else {
            int letterIndex=alphabet.indexOf(letter);
            int newLetterIndex=letterIndex+x;
            if (newLetterIndex>25){
                newLetterIndex=newLetterIndex-25;
            }
            if (newLetterIndex<0){
                newLetterIndex=newLetterIndex+25;
            }
            char newLetter=alphabet.charAt(newLetterIndex);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(letter)==true){
                char upper = Character.toUpperCase(newLetter);
                newLetter=upper;
            }
            System.out.print (newLetter);
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: It is suppose shift each letter of the word down one letter of the alphabet while maintaining capitalization and spaces.

Comment: When `letter` is not a lowercase letter, e.g. it is an uppercase letter or anything else, `letterIndex` will be **-1** (not found). So, all uppercase letters become `-1 + x = 0`, and `alphabet.charAt(0)` is **A**, so your code does exactly what you asked for. You'd have seen all this for yourself if you had debugged your code, so: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is shifting the letters by 1. 
That means: a -> b, b -> c, ... , z -> a, A -> B, B -> C, ... , Z -> A

The problem with your code and the capital letters is this line:

```
int letterIndex=alphabet.indexOf(letter);
```

When you search for `'A'`in your `String alphabet= ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");` the result is always 0. cause the char `'A'` is never found.

You can solve this when you use the `Character.toLowerCase()` in the line mentioned above like this:

```
char letterLowerCase = Character.toLowerCase(letter);
int letterIndex=alphabet.indexOf(letterLowerCase);
```

---

Apart from that:

- you can use a for-loop instead of the while-loop in combination with the index-variable.
- instead of checking the newLetterIndex>25 and substract it from newLetterIndex you can use the %-operator.

Here a slightly different version of your crunch-method:

```
public static void crunch(String word,int x) {
    String alphabet= ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {


        if (word.charAt(i)==' ') {
            System.out.print (" ");
        } else {

            int letterIndex=alphabet.indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(i)));
            int newLetterIndex= (letterIndex+x)%25;

            if (newLetterIndex<0){
                newLetterIndex=newLetterIndex+25;
            }

            char newLetter=alphabet.charAt(newLetterIndex);

            if (Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(i))==true){

                newLetter=Character.toUpperCase(newLetter);
            }
            System.out.print (newLetter);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your else a little bit

```
        boolean isUpper = Character.isUpperCase(letter);
        int letterIndex=alphabet.indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(letter));
        int newLetterIndex=letterIndex+x;
        if (newLetterIndex>25){
            newLetterIndex=newLetterIndex-25;
        }
        if (newLetterIndex<0){
            newLetterIndex=newLetterIndex+25;
        }
        char newLetter=alphabet.charAt(newLetterIndex);
        if (isUpper){
            char upper = Character.toUpperCase(newLetter);
            newLetter=upper;
        }
        System.out.print (newLetter);
        index++;
```

when you find upper letter you should transform to lower before get his code